# Apache: Blocking bad bots and site rippers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Today, i read this article: 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml

.Is it good and recommend to add in htaccess files ? I want know everyone's idea. I have no exp with this .

Answer (score 2):

I have this on my servers for at least 6 years. No just this but stuff to prevent hotlink of images on other sites. I think you have nothing to lose.

Comment: Do you have anything update this article ( list and... or remove any line ) ?

Comment: it is impossible to have a full list of all crappy rippers around, because as soon as you finish a "definitive" list more will appear. I recognize several famous rippers on this list but the best thing you can do is look into your logs each month and update the list with the new contenders you will probably find. Some people block completely entire countries as China and others but this may be too radical, because you can block a legitimate user. One thing you can do is to build traps to catch rippers. One classical example can be built with the robots.txt file.

Comment: this trap works like this: you create a directory on the root of your web server called, for example, "important". On your robots.txt you put the line "Disallow: /important". This line is instructing the search engine not to follow the stuff that is on that directory and all serious search engines will respect that. The rippers will not. So, you put a script inside /important that adds the visitor IP on the black list and one mili second later the server starts blocking that IP from reading any page.